# C# socket - how to correctly handle line ending

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I received an 3rd party exe which listens on port `1234` and expects number e.g `5000` ended with new line character and returns output for it

but for some reason e.g when I send just `0` then it gets stuck and when I restart both my listener and this exe then I feel like I received previous response

Or I send `1` it returns e.g `TRUE` and when I send `1` once again then it returns `FALSE`, so it seems to do not handle those inputs separately, as if that was not aware of it being OTHER message

I guess there's some problem with my code, but I can't know because I don't have code of this 3rd party.

I believe I handle line ending wrong

```
using System.Net;   
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;


var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
var remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
socket.Connect(remoteEndPoint);

while (true)
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] byData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s + "\r\n"); // I tried also \r \\r \n \\n \\r\\n
    socket.Send(byData);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int length = socket.Receive(buffer);
    char[] chars = new char[length];

    Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(buffer, 0, length, chars, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(new string(chars));
}
```

Comment: seems like that was `"\r\n\0"`, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit as searching in he dark; but you could try to append the NULL character `\0`.

So basically: `\n\0` or `\r\n\0`. `NULL` character is sometimes used (in)correctly to determine the end of a string, especially in older C like systems.

You can read more about it here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character